# Can I trust a site that includes "resources that are not secure"?

Tags: website, certificate

A friend wants to buy something from a website called stuffedsafari.com, however when she visits it, the `https` is stroke through, even though the certificate belongs to the site.

[image]

Would that still be a safe purchase? Do I have to worry about anything?

Comment: There's been some world-wide crap going on with ssl (thus https) lately. So that *could* be legit. I wouldn't care too much until the page that actually asks for payment info. Personally, I generally won't buy online from a seller that doesn't provide a well-trusted 3rd party payment option (like Paypal or Google Checkout).

Comment: PayPal is "well trusted"? Not by everyone, to say the least.

Comment: I rewrote the question so it didn't fall under the "too localized" criteria. I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @slhck You are a sweetie and the question is much improved. I'd withdraw my close vote now if that were possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that some portions of the page are being transmitted over http, that in itself is not necessarily bad, but it would make me question the overall safety of the site - a competent vendor would ensure that their site does not produce cert errors.

If you want to see what parts of the page were transmitted unencrypted you could install the firebug addon to FireFox.

Comment: There is no "cert error" on the website.

Comment: bryan is referring to the error you are seeing, which is in relation to certificates in that the certificate *should* be being used for encrypting all content on the page but is not and so you are seeing the error.  Most likely it is images or pulled in scripts that are causign the issue.  If I were you I would send the vendor a note saying you won't be using their site for purchase until resolved.  You should not have to fire up firebug to work out whether they are transmitting your data encrypted or not.